# RAILS: paperclip and creation date based directory structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, paperclip, attachment, interpolation

does anyone know how I can configure my rails model, which is using paperclip for data storage, to use creation date based directories like for example in fleximage ??

At present I'm using:

```
has_attached_file :bookblock, :path => "#{CONF['storage_path']}bookblock/:id_partition/:style.:content_type_ehas_attached_filextension"
```

but what I need is something like this

```
has_attached_file :bookblock, :path => "#    {CONF['storage_path']}bookblock/:created_at_year/:created_at_month/:created_at_day/:c:id_partition/:style.:content_type_ehas_attached_filextension"
```

a simple :created_at in the directory path would also help

```
{CONF['storage_path']}/:created_at/bookblock/:id_partition/:style.:content_type_ehas_attached_filextension"
```

Thanx in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 5):

You can add your own interpolations to Paperclip. To give a simple example:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :year do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.created_at.year
end
```

Now you can use `:year` in the `:path` option like this:

```
has_attached_file :bookblock, :path => "#{CONF['storage_path']}bookblock/:year/:id/:style.:content_type_ehas_attached_filextension"
```

You could define three interpolations: `:year`, `:month` and `:day`, or just one that returns the whole year/month/day string.

Comment: thanx a lot ;) now that I know the name "interpolation", I could find everything on : https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations